# Pagination code being triggered upon launch instead of when user reaches bottom of page

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll/pagination feature to a table view. I use `scrollViewDidScroll` to measure when the user reaches the bottom of the page, which then triggers a function to fetch the next batch of data. However I think the measurements are off because my `fetchMoreEvents` function is being triggered upon the launch of the app.

This is the pagination code (`scrollViewDidScroll` and `fetchMoreEvents`):

```
func fetchMoreEvents() {
    fetchingMore = true
    var page = 1
    page += 1

    let seatGeekApiUrl = URL(string: "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?venue.state=NY&page=\(page)&client_id=MTM5OTE0OTd8MTU0MjU2NTQ4MC4z")!

    fetchData(url: seatGeekApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Welcome>) -> (Void) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.eventData.append(contentsOf: object.events)
            print("\neventData: \n\n\(self.eventData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\nError decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    print("\nFetching next batch of events: (Page \(page))\n")
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height {
        if !fetchingMore {
            fetchMoreEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

Once `fetchMoreEvents` is triggered, I have it append my `eventData` array with the next page of results and reload the table view. My print statement confirms that it fetches page 2 of the data, but like I said that happens immediately instead of when I scroll down the page. Also, it never gets triggered again.

**Is this an issue with the measurements in `scrollViewDidScroll`, or am I going wrong somewhere else?**

These are the table view methods if they're applicable here:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return eventData.count
    } else if section == 1 && fetchingMore {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventsCell", for: indexPath) as! EventsTableViewCell

        let event = eventData[indexPath.row]

        // Labels
        cell.eventNameLabel.text = event.title
        cell.eventVenueLabel.text = event.venue.nameV2
        cell.eventAddressLabel.text = event.venue.address
        cell.eventTimeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: event.dateTimeLocal)

        // Image
        if let urlString = event.performers[0].image, let imageURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: imageURL) { (image) in
                cell.eventImageView.image = image
            }
        }
        else {
            cell.eventImageView.image = UIImage(named: "noImageFound")
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadingCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell

        cell.spinner.startAnimating()

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks to me like the frames aren't what you expect in scrollViewDidScroll. possibly called before the views are fully laid out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an Bool as property

```
var isAllRowSeeked: Bool = false
```

Put this logic in your `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
let  height = scrollView.frame.size.height
let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
if distanceFromBottom < height,
   self.isAllRowSeeked == true {
   // you've reached the end, you are now ready to load more data

   self.isAllRowSeeked = false
}
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 if  fetchingMore == true,
        isLastSectionRow(indexPath: indexPath) {// it's the last row of this section
        state.isAllRowSeeked = true
        return paginatorUI?.getPaginatedLoadMoreCell()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
```

Add the following method

```
public func isLastSectionRow(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            let lastSection = tableview.dataSource?.numberOfSections?(in: tableview)
                ?? 1
            let lastRow = tableview.dataSource?.tableView(tableview,
                                                          numberOfRowsInSection: indexPath.section)
                ?? 0

            return lastSection == (indexPath.section+1) && lastRow == (indexPath.row+1)
    }
```

Actually this logic is borrowed from one of my [pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TableviewPaginator), which you can use. Complete code for this pagination can be found [here](https://github.com/ratulSharker/TableviewPaginator/blob/master/TableviewPaginator/Classes/TableviewPaginator.swift)

Comment: Tried this and the same issue is happening. As soon as I run the app the first thing printed to the console is `Fetching next batch of events: (Page 2)`. Then once the bottom is reached nothing else is triggered.

Comment: Actually, I took away the `if !fetchingMore` condition and it seems to have infinite scroll now, but it constantly fetches page 2 over and over. It's also triggered immediately upon launch of the app.

Comment: i've updated the answer, actually i missed few chcking previously.

Comment: If the answer is so bad that receives negative votes, please consider yourself to put a comment with proper reasoning.

Comment: Hey Ratul it wasn't me that downvoted your answer. I upvoted it back to 0 for you though. I haven't had a chance to try your solution. I'm running into a separate issue so I think I'm going to post a separate question.

Comment: I understand, it happens to me sometimes as well and it's very frustrating. Downvotes are fine but I feel like people can at least explain what their issue is with the question or answer.

Comment: Hey I just marked your answer correct, I haven't tried the rest of the code but I'm using your `scrollViewDidScroll` logic - thanks for your help!

Comment: Please let me know the update, if its works for you.